# MySQL query using 4 tables, LEFT JOINs and WHERE EXISTS

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I have a total of four (4) tables I need to work with.  Essentially one pulls from the other to grab data which pulls from another to grab the previous tables data and so on.

I am having trouble getting a query that will successfully run without timing out.  I want to show the `SUM` of `VISITS` for a Commodity, along with its Total Sales during a given time period in `ORDER` of `MONTH`

**Table Structures**

```
table1 (WebVisits)
ID   DATE        WEBNUMBER  VISITS
1    2012-01-01  apw-rtr8   2
..   ...         ...        ..


table2 (Commodities)
ID      WEBNUMBER   TIER1
5791    apw-rtr8    Refrigeration
..      ...         ...


table3 (Attributes)
ITEM        WEB_NUM
APW-RTR-8   apw-rtr8
..          ...


table4 (SalesData)
ID     ITEM        QUANTITY  UNIT_PRICE  TRANS_DATE
31905  APW-RTR-8   1         1522.38     2012-02-05
..     ...         ...       ...         ...

SELECT 
    MONTH(t1.DATE) AS MONTH, 
    SUM(t1.VISITS) as Visits,
    t2.TIER1 as Category
FROM
    table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.WEBNUMBER = t2.WEBNUMBER
        LEFT JOIN
    table3 t3 ON t2.WEBNUMBER = t3.WEB_NUM
WHERE
    t1.DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-05-31'
        AND t3.TIER1 = 'Cooking Equipment '
        AND EXISTS( SELECT 
            sum(t4.UNIT_PRICE * t4.QUANTITY) as total
        FROM
            table4 t4
        WHERE
            t4.ITEM = t3.ITEM
                AND t4.TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-05-31')
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH
```

Basically the Category (TIER1) will be already known and the Date ranges will be known.  I want it to spit out results similar to this given the query above:

```
MONTH   Visits  Total     Category
1       4054    32058.08  Cooking Equipment 
2       3564    28116.17  Cooking Equipment 
3       4514    25819.66  Cooking Equipment 
4       3621    18732.96  Cooking Equipment 
5       6521    55378.11  Cooking Equipment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to write the query and realized that I wrote nearly the same query as you've written.

Make sure the following `indexes` exists:

```
table1.DATE
table1.WEBNUMBER
table2.WEBNUMBER
table3.WEB_NUM
table4.ITEM
table4.TRANS_DATE
```

Edit:

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(table1.DATE) AS MONTH, 
    SUM(table1.VISITS) as Visits, 
    table2.TIER1 as Category, 
    SUM(table4.UNIT_PRICE * table4.QUANTITY) 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 USING(WEBNUMBER) 
LEFT JOIN table3 table1.WEBNUMBER = table3.WEB_NUM 
LEFT JOIN table4 table1.WEBNUMBER = table4.ITEM 
WHERE table2.TIER1 = 'Cooking Equipment' 
AND table4.TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' 
AND '2012-05-31' 
GROUP BY MONTH 
ORDER BY MONTH
```

Comment: table1 `ID` is PRIMARY | table2 `ID` is PRIMARY, `WEBNUMBER` is INDEXED | table3 `ITEM` is PRIMARY, `WEB_NUM` is INDEXED | table4 `ID` is PRIMARY

Comment: Thank you this is a great start.  I have added the indexes as you instructed and the query runs very fast.  I had to add in the `WHERE` `AND table2.TIER1 ='Cooking Equipment '`

Comment: No problem! I saw that I completely missed the WHERE statement AND the table2.TIER part, added it.

Comment: So I have done more thorough testing and the results are not accurate.  My Main goal is to simply track the SALES of those Products with Visits during a given time period

Comment: The `VISITS` and the total sales are highly inflated...I belive it has something to do with the `SUM` attributes?